# How to combine Vim's and Pydiction's Autocomplete Functionality?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I'm wondering if there is a way to **combine** Vim's **built-in autocomplete** functionality with something like **pydiction** (autocompletes python dict only at the moment)? I'd like to have autocompletion for my created variables.

Currently I have to use Tab to autocomplete python code and Ctrl-N to autocomplete my variables and I would like **both to happen** when Tab is pressed.

Pydiction Addon: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this yet, but just pointing you in the (hopefully) right direction.

SuperTab plugin does all insert-mode completion with Tab.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=182

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what I want, but it's a lot better than what I was doing. Thanks.